# Make Unique Values in One Column to multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data:

| Age | Bank | Amount in Bank |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 13 | A | 50 |
| 13 | B | 20 |
| 14 | C | 70 |
| 15 | D | 20 |
| 16 | E | 100 |
| 16 | E | 15 |
| 16 | F | 10 |

and I want to separate the unique names under into its own individual columns and matching the amount to its individual so at last I want to achieve this:

| Age | A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13 | 50 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 13 |  | 20 |  |  |  |  |
| 14 |  |  | 70 |  |  |  |
| 15 |  |  |  | 20 |  |  |
| 16 |  |  |  |  | 100 |  |
| 16 |  |  |  |  | 15 |  |
| 16 |  |  |  |  |  | 10 |

So I have tried this and it enables me to split to its individual column and all but when I add in "age" column the whole table becomes weird. I also want to fill the empty cells with 0. With "data" being the dataframe of the first table,

```
df_age = pd.DataFrame(data['Age']) #extract the age in another new dataframe
group = data.groupby(['Bank']) 
df = group.apply(lambda x: x['Amount in Bank'].unique())
df = df.apply(pd.Series)
df_trans = df.transpose() #to make it a column
new_Data = pd.concat([df_trans, df_age]) #new_Data being the new table I want to achieve
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Why do you want the Age column to be in a different row for each unique value? This looks just like a pivot, but you make it unnecessary complex

Comment: Looks like you want: `df.pivot_table(index="Age", columns="Bank", values="Amount in Bank", fill_value='')`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
(df
    .set_index('Age')
    .apply(lambda row: pd.Series([row['Amount in Bank']], index=[row['Bank']]), axis=1)
    .reset_index()
)
```

Comment: This somehow gives me NAN values not sure if it is because of the set_index() thing

Comment: Also, looks like this would work:

`df.pivot_table(index="Age", columns="Bank", values="Amount in Bank", fill_value='')`

from @Erfan